# How to catch error when parameters is missng using req.params? - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, parameters

I have code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


app.get('/test/:name', (req, res) => {

const {name} = req.params;
res.send(`Parameters: ${name}`)
})
```

when i type **localhost:3000/test/** i get error

> Cannot GET /test/

When use param -  **localhost:3000/test/*anyParam*** - all is okay.

How to set default value or other way to prevent this error? I want show page with error (execute code when parameter is missing - sb just go to **localhost:3000/test/**) without error from node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

//get with optional parametres
app.get('/test/:name?', (req, res) => {
   const {name} = req.params;
   if(name){
       res.send(`Parameters: ${name}`)
   } else {
      res.send(`missing parametres`)
   }
})
```